# Launch template mtc should not specify an instance profile. The noderole in your request will be used to construct an instance profile

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

My launch template specifies an iam instance profile and my node group has a groupe role arn. Based on this error, I removed the **iam_instance_role** argument from my template resource block and it still gave me the same error

```
Launch template mtc should not specify an instance profile. The noderole in your request will be used to construct an instance profile."
```

Here's my launch template resource blocks **with** my instance profile included

```
resource "aws_launch_template" "node" {
  image_id                             = var.image_id
  instance_type                        = var.instance_type
  key_name                             = var.key_name
  instance_initiated_shutdown_behavior = "terminate"
  name                                 = var.name
  user_data                            = base64encode("node_userdata.tpl")
#   vpc_security_group_ids               = var.security_group_ids

    block_device_mappings {
        device_name = "/dev/sda1"

    ebs {
      volume_size = 20
    }
  }

  iam_instance_profile {
    name = aws_iam_instance_profile.node.name
  }

  monitoring {
    enabled = true
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "node" {
  name_prefix = var.name
  role        = aws_iam_role.node.id
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "node" {
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.assume_role_ec2.json
  name               = var.name
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "assume_role_ec2" {
  statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
    effect  = "Allow"

    principals {
      identifiers = ["ec2.amazonaws.com"]
      type        = "Service"
    }
  }
}
```

When I first tried to apply this I got that error, so I removed all of it and tried again **without** the instance profile like-so:

```
resource "aws_launch_template" "node" {
  image_id                             = var.image_id
  instance_type                        = var.instance_type
  key_name                             = var.key_name
  instance_initiated_shutdown_behavior = "terminate"
  name                                 = var.name
  user_data                            = base64encode("node_userdata.tpl")
#   vpc_security_group_ids               = var.security_group_ids

    block_device_mappings {
        device_name = "/dev/sda1"

    ebs {
      volume_size = 20
    }
  }

  monitoring {
    enabled = true
  }
}
```

Got the same error both times. Here's my **node group** resource block as well

```
resource "aws_eks_node_group" "nodes_eks" {

  cluster_name    = aws_eks_cluster.eks.name
  node_group_name = "eks-node-group"
  node_role_arn   = aws_iam_role.eks_nodes.arn
  subnet_ids      = module.vpc.private_subnets
  # remote_access {
  #   ec2_ssh_key = aws_key_pair.bastion_auth.id

  # }

  scaling_config {
    desired_size = 3
    max_size     = 6
    min_size     = 3
  }

  ami_type             = "CUSTOM"
  capacity_type        = "ON_DEMAND"

  force_update_version = false
  # instance_types       = [var.instance_type]
  labels = {
    role = "nodes-pool-1"
  }

  launch_template {
    id      = aws_launch_template.node.id
    version = aws_launch_template.node.default_version
  }

  # version = var.k8s_version

  depends_on = [
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.amazon_eks_worker_node_policy,
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.amazon_eks_cni_policy,
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.amazon_ec2_container_registry_read_only,
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, there are multiple points to take care of starting with [1]:

> An object representing a node group launch template specification. The launch template cannot include `SubnetId`, `IamInstanceProfile`, `RequestSpotInstances`, `HibernationOptions`, or `TerminateInstances`, or the node group deployment or update will fail.

As per the document [2], you cannot specify any of the:

1. Instance profile - the node IAM role will be used
2. Subnets - the `subnet_ids` will be used and they are defined also in the node configuration
3. Shutdown behavior - EKS controls the instance lifecycle

Note that in the table it says **prohibited** which means it cannot ever be used. Additionally, in [2], you can find this as well:

> Some of the settings in a launch template are similar to the settings used for managed node configuration. When deploying or updating a node group with a launch template, some settings must be specified in either the node group configuration or the launch template. Don't specify both places. **If a setting exists where it shouldn't, then operations such as creating or *updating* a node group fail.**

So you were pretty close when you removed the `iam_instance_profile`, but you still have to get rid of the `instance_initiated_shutdown_behavior` argument:

```
resource "aws_launch_template" "node" {
  image_id       = var.image_id
  instance_type  = var.instance_type
  key_name       = var.key_name
  name           = var.name
  user_data      = base64encode("node_userdata.tpl")

  block_device_mappings {
    device_name = "/dev/sda1"

    ebs {
      volume_size = 20
    }
  }

  monitoring {
    enabled = true
  }
}
```

I strongly suggest reading through the second document as it contains a lot of useful information about what to do when using a custom AMI.

---

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/APIReference/API_LaunchTemplateSpecification.html

[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/launch-templates.html#launch-template-basics

Comment: I removed the shutdown behavior argument as well and still got the same error, I'll try a full destroy and redeploy of all my resources which will take a little while and see if that fixes it

Comment: After redeploying everything I got the "Instance failed to join cluster" error with, with no other information